# VB6: Displaying an icon in a picture box

Tags: vb6, icons, picturebox

I'm essentially just trying to draw an icon image in a picture box.

I have the following subroutine. Input parameters verified and correct, however the icon does not display in the picture box when `DrawIcon` is called (this is part of a larger class).

```
Public Sub Draw_Icon(ByVal strDefaultIcon As String, ByVal lngIconNumber As Long, ByRef Picture_hDC As Long)

Dim lngIcon As Long
Dim lngError As Long

    lngIcon = ExtractIcon(App.hInstance, strDefaultIcon, lngIconNumber)

    If (lngIcon = 1 Or lngIcon = 0) Then
        Call No_Icon(Picture_hDC)
    Else
        lngError = DrawIcon(Picture_hDC, 0, 0, lngIcon)
        lngError = DestroyIcon(lngIcon)
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?  I've tried a number of solutions from StackOverflow and other sites to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answers. I fixed the issue with the following. I used a hidden, temporary image and picture box control to store the icon or image, respectively. Their contents are used to populate controls on the parent form. I hope that the code is readable. Thank you very much once again.

' Calling code
'
Public Function GetPictureOrIconAsImage(ByVal sFilename As String) As Picture

Dim strDefaultIcon As String
Dim lngIconNumber As Long
Dim Icon As New clsIcon

```
' Set error handler
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler   

picTempPicture.Picture = LoadPicture("")
picTempIcon.Picture = LoadPicture("")

' Return picture if this is a picture file, otherwise attempt to return icon
If (modEasyQProcs.IsPictureFile(sFilename)) Then
    picTempPicture.Picture = LoadPicture(sFilename)
    Set GetPictureOrIconAsImage = picTempPicture.Picture
Else
    If (Icon.GetDefaultIcon(sFilename, lngIconNumber, strDefaultIcon)) Then
        Call Icon.Draw_Icon(strDefaultIcon, lngIconNumber, picTempIcon.hDC)
    Else
        Call Icon.No_Icon(picTempIcon.hDC)
    End If

    Set GetPictureOrIconAsImage = picTempIcon.Image
End If

Exit Function
```

ErrorHandler:   ' Generic error handler
    Call NonCriticalError(MODULE, Err, "GetPictureOrIconAsImage:ErrorHandler")
    Err.Clear

```
' End of error handler scope
On Error GoTo 0
```

End Function

' Class Icon
'
Public Function GetDefaultIcon(ByRef FileName As String, ByRef lngIconNumber As Long, ByRef strDefaultIcon As String) As Boolean
    'Parameters:
    'FileName: The extension of the filename, with the "." e.g .doc
    'Picture_hDC: The Handle to the device context of the Picture Box you want the icon
    'to be displayed on.
    'Example:
    'Call GetDefaultIcon(".doc",Picture1.hDC)

```
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim lngError As Long
Dim lngRegKeyHandle As Long
Dim strProgramName As String
Dim lngStringLength As Long
Dim lngIcon As Long
Dim intN As Integer

GetDefaultIcon = False

TempFileName = Right(FileName, Len(FileName) - InStrRev(FileName, ".") + 1)

If (LCase(TempFileName) = ".exe") Then
    strDefaultIcon = Space(260)
    lngStringLength = GetSystemDirectory(strDefaultIcon, 260)
    strDefaultIcon = Left(strDefaultIcon, lngStringLength) & "\SHELL32.DLL"
    lngIconNumber = 2

    GetDefaultIcon = True
Else
    lngError = RegOpenKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TempFileName, lngRegKeyHandle)
    If (lngError = 0) Then
        lngStringLength = 260
        strProgramName = Space$(260)

        lngError = RegQueryValueEx(lngRegKeyHandle, vbNullString, 0, 0, strProgramName, lngStringLength)
        If (lngError = 0) Then
            lngError = RegCloseKey(lngRegKeyHandle)

            lngError = RegCloseKey(lngRegKeyHandle)
            strProgramName = Left(strProgramName, lngStringLength - 1)
            lngError = RegOpenKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, strProgramName & "\DefaultIcon", lngRegKeyHandle)

            If (lngError = 0) Then
                lngStringLength = 260
                strDefaultIcon = Space$(260)
                lngError = RegQueryValueEx(lngRegKeyHandle, vbNullString, 0, 0, strDefaultIcon, lngStringLength)
                If (lngError) Then
                    lngError = RegCloseKey(lngRegKeyHandle)
                Else
                    lngError = RegCloseKey(lngRegKeyHandle)
                    strDefaultIcon = Trim$(Left(strDefaultIcon, lngStringLength - 1))

                    intN = InStrRev(strDefaultIcon, ",")

                    If (intN >= 1) Then
                        lngIconNumber = Trim$(Right(strDefaultIcon, Len(strDefaultIcon) - intN))
                        strDefaultIcon = Trim$(Left(strDefaultIcon, intN - 1))

                        GetDefaultIcon = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

End Function

Public Sub Draw_Icon(ByVal strDefaultIcon As String, ByVal lngIconNumber As Long, ByRef Picture_hDC As Long)

Dim lngIcon As Long
Dim lngError As Long

```
lngIcon = ExtractIcon(App.hInstance, strDefaultIcon, lngIconNumber)

If (lngIcon = 1 Or lngIcon = 0) Then
    Call No_Icon(Picture_hDC)
Else
    lngError = DrawIcon(Picture_hDC, 0, 0, lngIcon)

    If (lngError) Then lngError = DestroyIcon(lngIcon)
End If
```

End Sub

Public Sub No_Icon(ByRef Picture_hDC As Long)

Dim strDefaultIcon As String
Dim lngIconNumber As Long
Dim lngStringLength As Long

```
'No icon could be found so we use the normal windows icon
'This icon is held in shell32.dll in the system directory, Icon 0
strDefaultIcon = Space(260)
lngStringLength = GetSystemDirectory(strDefaultIcon, 260)
strDefaultIcon = Left(strDefaultIcon, lngStringLength) & "\SHELL32.DLL"
lngIconNumber = 0
Call Draw_Icon(strDefaultIcon, lngIconNumber, Picture_hDC)
```

End Sub